# textbox on each tabpage in tabcontrol

Tags: c#, xml, tabs, textbox

I am new to c#. I have a tab control with 3 textboxes. On button click I add a new tabpage with clone textbox.

code:

```
TabPage tpQueriesFree = new TabPage("Queries" + (tabCQueries.TabCount + 1).ToString());
tpQueriesFree.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
tbSqlProviderName.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(111, 4);
tbSqlProviderName.Name = "tbSqlProviderName" + (tabCQueries.TabCount + 1).ToString();
tbSqlProviderName.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(364, 20);
tbSqlProviderName.TabIndex = 1;
tbSqlProviderName.Text = "System.Data.SqlClient";
tpQueriesFree.Controls.Add(lblSQLProvideName1);
tpQueriesFree.Controls.Add(tbSqlProviderName1);
```

I added a new button for writing to the xml file.
When I click the button I need to write tbtbSqlProviderName for each tabpage with:

```
xml.WriteElementString("SqlConnectionString", tbSQLConnString.Text);
```

what do I need to do to get

```
xml.WriteElementString("SqlConnectionString", tbSQLConnString.Text);
```

for each tabpage?

Comment: Your question still not clear. What you want to do? Getting any error? Getting problem in creating new tab? getting problem in generating xml? or failed to retrieve connection string? Wait.. You have stored connection string in tabpage text property!!

Comment: @Winky
I need help how to write xml string for all tabpage. I know how to write xml string for first tabpage. I need to read connection string form textbox for each page. I hope that you understand me :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a `foreach`, like so:

```
foreach (TabPage tp in tabControl1.TabPages)
{
    foreach (TextBox tb in tp.Controls)
    {
         xml.WriteElementString("SqlConnectionString", tbSQLConnString.Text);
    }
}
```

Is this what you wanted?

Glad to help.